# Changing viewport doesn`t do anything [Blogger]

Tags: html, blogger

On Blogger I'm using the Awesome Inc. template but it doesn't sCale nicely on mobile or when changing the window size. Editing the HTML I noticed there was a viewport tag but changing or deleting it didn't so anything. Adding a new viewport tag also doesn't do anything. I am wondering what I can do to make it work.

Thanks in advance,
Rover

Comment: What atttributes are given in view port?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have this correctly in the `<head></head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

And did you use media queries in CSS correctly? This is an example of How it could be:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
body {
/*Your Code here*/
  }
}
```